# Executing multiple cURL requests

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I am trying to sequentially execute multiple curl requests, but I am not really having any luck, here is my code thus far,

```
//upload photo
$file= 'photo.jpg';
$args = array(
    'message' => 'Photo from application',
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$args_two = array(
    'message' => 'This is a test post',
);

$ch_two = curl_init();
$url_two = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token='.$token;
curl_setopt($ch_two, CURLOPT_URL, $url_two);
curl_setopt($ch_two, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch_two, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_two, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch_two, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args_two);
$data_two = curl_exec($ch_two);
```

This file gets called and then the two requests should be executed one after the other, but right now it's just not working.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I suggest that you use facebooks php sdk
http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

Comment: I have gotten it to upload individually with the above code, but as soon as I put it all in one file, it breaks, so I need to find the right way to execute multiple curl requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [curl_close](http://ru.php.net/curl_close)
Try to use the same curl resource for two requests
Check if is it true, that none of requests is send to servers